# Updating Controller Object Properties in the console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

Not sure if this is possible, but I have some content with an ng-if that I want to test by updating a property on one of the controller's variables within the console.

```
  <div class="manager-only" ng-if="teamSchedule.userObject.isManager">
    <a href="#add-game">
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add New Game" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

As you can probably surmise, the userObject has an isManager property that is a boolean. On page load, it's initially set to false. I'm trying to update this within the console to test the ng-if.

I found that I could add `window.teamSchedule = teamSchedule;` to the controller in order to have a reference to it and its variables within the console, and this does allow me to change the object properties of the userObject, it appears. However the ng-if does not seem to respond to the change.

I've tried changing the ng-if to an ng-show and that didn't seem to work either. Anyone have a way to make this work or know if it's not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `$scope.apply()` do the trick?

Comment: I haven't had time to test at the moment. Trying to meet a deadline and will have to go back and try. Have just moved on for now.

Answer (score 0):

First explanation why it doesn't work.

You change the Object out of the AngularJs scope, so Angular doesn't realize that you changed something.

If you don't use production mode on your development system, you can use this to access the scope.

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

`$0` is the last element selected in the chrome element inspector.

Try to access your object this way, if this does not trigger the changes, try to use

```
scope.$apply(function() { your modification })
```